# Компактная запись .querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Допустим есть код:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btn[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(btn[0].textContent);
});
btn[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(btn[1].textContent);
});
btn[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(btn[2].textContent);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button>click me</button>
  <button>click my</button>
  <button>click im</button>
</body>
```

Вопрос: Возможно ли написать более компактную запись: btn[i].addEventListener(..) (или что-то еще) чтобы не перечислять каждую по отдельности? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Возможно ли написать более компактную запись: btn[i].addEventListener(..)

Да, возможно, для этого надо использовать [цикл `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener(...)
}
```

При этом, чтобы внутри обработчика обращаться к нужной кнопке достаточно использовать для этого `this`

```
console.log(this.textContent);
```

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.textContent);
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>click me</button>
  <button>click my</button>
  <button>click im</button>
</body>
```

Comment: +1. Это мне понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Во первых, `querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию, которую можно перебрать:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(btn.textContent);
    })
  });
```

```html
<body>
  <button>click me</button>
  <button>click my</button>
  <button>click im</button>

</body>
```

Во вторых, можно обойтись одним обработчиком событий:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <button>click me</button>
  <button>click my</button>
  <button>click im</button>

</body>
```

Comment: `forEach` для NodeList реализован не во всех браузерах

Answer (score 4):

Можно кнопки перебрать.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btn.forEach(c => {
    c.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(c.textContent)
    })
})
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
     <button>click my</button>
     <button>click im</button>
```

Comment: `forEach` для NodeList реализован не во всех браузерах

Answer (score 1):

Взято из [learn.javascript.ru.](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B0)

> Если есть много элементов, события на которых нужно обрабатывать
>   похожим образом, то вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик каждому –
>   ставится один обработчик на их общего предка. Из него можно получить
>   целевой элемент event.target, понять на каком именно потомке произошло
>   событие и обработать его.

Хороший пример обработчика и для абсолютно разных действий.

```
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
  <button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
  <button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>

<script>
  function Menu(elem) {
    this.save = function() {
      alert( 'сохраняю' );
    };
    this.load = function() {
      alert( 'загружаю' );
    };
    this.search = function() {
      alert( 'ищу' );
    };

    var self = this;

    elem.onclick = function(e) {
      var target = e.target;
      var action = target.getAttribute('data-action');
      if (action) {
        self[action]();
      }
    };
  }

  new Menu(menu);
</script>
```

про data атрибут [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-dataset-data-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: _я бы не стал подвешиваться на все button_ - почему?

Comment: @Grundy Был вопрос,как можно компактнее и не перечислять каждую по отдельности?К чему тут цикл?

Comment: имелось ввиду не прописывать руками каждую кнопку. Цикл вполне подходит для этого. Но это никак не отвечает на мой вопрос в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @Grundy потому что однотипные элементы.

Comment: Что однотипные элементы?

Comment: @Grundy В предыдущем комментарии Вы хотели конкретного ответа,мой ответ потому что однотипные элементы,оптимизация(чем цикл или метод forEach(который Вам тоже почему-то не понравился,не вижу проблемы если использовать prototype).Если Вы не согласны,буду рад услышать почему.

Comment: как _однотипность элементов_ связана с использованием или неиспользованием цикла?

Comment: @Grundy У вас три обработчика,у меня был бы один.

Comment: Наконец-то кто-то пор всплытие написал. Только вот пример не очень...